# Binary adder only working *most* of the time

Tags: c, binary, addition

I'm currently working on a binary adder.

Register A and B are the input registers. They are stored as doubly-linked lists. Register S is for output. (For the truth table)

Here is the truth table provided:

A | B | CarryIn | S | CarryOut

0 | 0 | 0       | 0 | 0

0 | 0 | 1       | 1 | 0

0 | 1 | 0       | 1 | 0

0 | 1 | 1       | 0 | 1

1 | 0 | 0       | 1 | 0

1 | 0 | 1       | 0 | 1

1 | 1 | 0       | 0 | 1

1 | 1 | 1       | 1 | 1

Here is the structure (CPU) that holds pointers to them, along with other data:

```
struct cpu_t
{
        int word_size; 
        int unsign; 
        int overflow; 
        int carry;
        int sign;
        int parity;
        int zero;
        struct bit_t *r1_head;
        struct bit_t *r1_tail;
        struct bit_t *r2_head;
        struct bit_t *r2_tail;
        struct bit_t *r3_head;
        struct bit_t *r3_tail;
};
```

And here is my add function:

```
void add_function(struct cpu_t *cpu)
{
    int i = 0;

    struct bit_t *temp1 = cpu->r1_tail;
    struct bit_t *temp2 = cpu->r2_tail;
    struct bit_t *temp3 = cpu->r3_tail;

    while(i < (cpu->word_size))
    {
        if(temp1->n == 0 && temp2->n == 0 && cpu->carry == 0)
        {
            temp3->n = 0;   
            cpu->carry = 0;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 0 && temp2->n == 0 && cpu->carry == 1)
        {
            temp3->n = 1;   
            cpu->carry = 0;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 0 && temp2->n == 1 && cpu->carry == 0)
        {
            temp3->n = 1;   
            cpu->carry = 0;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 0 && temp2->n == 1 && cpu->carry == 1)
        {
            temp3->n = 0;   
            cpu->carry = 1;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 1 && temp2->n == 0 && cpu->carry == 0)
        {
            temp3->n = 1;   
            cpu->carry = 0;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 1 && temp2->n == 0 && cpu->carry == 1)
        {
            temp3->n = 0;   
            cpu->carry = 1;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 1 && temp2->n == 1 && cpu->carry == 0)
        {
            temp3->n = 0;   
            cpu->carry = 1;
        }
        else if(temp1->n == 1 && temp2->n == 1 && cpu->carry == 1)
        {
            temp3->n = 1;   
            cpu->carry = 1;
        }

        temp1 = temp1->prev;
        temp2 = temp2->prev;
        temp3 = temp3->prev;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here is some sample output to show the kind of issue I'm having:

With a word_size of 2:

01 + 01 = 10 (correct)

With a word_size of 4:

0111 + 0001 = 1001 (wrong)

With a word_size of 8:

10101010 + 01010101 = 11111111 (correct)

11101101 + 01101000 = 01010110 (incorrect, actual is 01010101)

With a word_size of 4:

1001 + 0110 = 1111 (correct)

1111 + 1111 = 1110 (correct)

So, based on this input, does anyone know why my code isn't working? Any ideas?

If you need me to edit in some more code, I think I can easily do that. If not, I'll just tell you what you need through the comments.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I would say all of the presented examples are correct.

Comment: EDIT: Nope. 0111 + 0001 should equal 1000. My calculator says it is 1001. What's up with that?

Comment: But in the question it reads `0111 + 0001 = 1000 (wrong)`.

Comment: When code does `0111 + 0001`, is `cpu->carry` set to 0 first?  Code may have an off by 1 from the previous calculation.

Comment: Sorry about that Eugene. It's very difficult for me to balance the answers I'm getting versus the answers I'm getting online. I was mixing a couple up. I'll fix that.

Comment: Gah, I honestly can't tell if my answers are right or wrong. I'm not sure the tool I was using online was correct anyways. D:

Comment: Thanks Chux! Looks like that might have been the issue after all! I just set the carry flag to zero at the beginning of the function and it seems fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's test cases expected the `cpu->carry` to have a 0 when doing the `void add_function(struct cpu_t *cpu)`.

Look like OP should have 2 add functions and use accordingly.

```
void addc_function(struct cpu_t *cpu) {
  // existing code 
}

void add_function(struct cpu_t *cpu) {
  cpu->carry = 0;
  addc_function(cpu);
}
```